# Where does this code return the mouse position value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying react, but there's something I can't understand.
Where does this code get the mouse position value?

```
function useMousePosition() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);

  const setPosition = ({ x, y }) => {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", setPosition);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", setPosition);
  }, []);

  return [x, y];
}
```

Comment: From the `MouseEvent` passed to the callback by `window.addEventListener`. This part is plain JS, and has nothing to do with React

Comment: I'm new to JS and React.. I didn't know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is here:

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", setPosition);
```

and here:

```js
const setPosition = ({ x, y }) => {
  setX(x);
  setY(y);
};
```

The first part listens for mouse movement, and when it happens, passes the data to the `x` and `y` variables of the `setPosition` function, the second part.

Comment: Can I get a value without ```clientX, Y```?
Thank you for answer.

Comment: How do you want to get the mouse positions if not using variables?